# How to merge several sets of text files

Tags: batch-file, merge

I have a directory containing aprox. 1500 textfiles with data.
I want to merge this data to several sets, because there are always 24 sets for each measuring data. like machine1-00.csv machine1-01.csv machine1-03.csv etc. and machine2-00.csv machine2-01.csv machine2-03.csv. I want to merge all the data from machine1*.csv into machine1.csv and all the data from machine2*.csv into machine2.csv. The command `copy /b machine1*.csv machine1.csv /y` works fine for one set, but how to do for 1500 machine sets, each having 24 files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution in my opinion is to create a small Windows batch script that iterates over the range from 1 to 24. For each value in the range, the script invokes a corresponding call of the copy instruction.

The following "merge.bat" file shoud do the job:

```
@echo off
FOR /L %%i IN (1, 1, 24) DO (

copy /b machine%%i*.csv machine%%i.csv /y

)
```

Simply create a text file (using notepad) named "merge.bat" with this content at the location of your csv files and run merge.bat You should be fine.

Comment: I just edited out an error: copy /b machine%%i*.csv machine%%G.csv /y -- %%G must be replaced with %%i

Comment: Thanks Eliasw. I made a mistake in formulating my question.
It leads to the assumption that "machinex" is the common part of the filename sets.
Sadly that's not the case. A set consists of 24 hourly taken measuring data (e.g. Level, Volume, Pressure etc)
So the filenames of Level would be Levelxx.csv, where xx ranges from 00-23
The same for Volume and Pressure.
In the example of Level, I want to merge the 24 hourly generated csv files of Level, to one like Level-day.csv
But I want to be able to do that for all the different kinds of data files

Answer (score 0):

Use `type machine1*.csv` and redirect the output to `newfile.csv` using `>`.  Something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /L %%I in (1,1,63) do (
    >merged%%I.csv type machine%%I*.csv
    ren merged%%I.csv machine%%I.csv
)
```

Change the 63 to whatever the greatest number is.  You could script detection of the greatest number, but this is easier.

If your CSV files don't end with a new line, this problem will need more attention, as neither `copy /b` nor `type` will append a new line between appended files.